# Get Arguments To Program Remotely

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have this code:

`arguments = urllib.urlopen("http://website.com.info/file.php")`

`command = location + "\file.exe " + arguments.read()`

I would like to be able to control the arguments remotely and this code works, But my problem my AV block this behavior because it tries to access a website or something. Any alternative way to be able to pass arguments to my program remotely?

I use python2.6 and this program run on windows (py2exe)

P.S this is used on my own computers I'm trying to control the arguments remotely when I'm not around.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Without clarification, it sounds like you need Dbus, TCP, or some other IPC route for communicating between your target and the remote... but again, I'm not sure what the problem is.  Are you trying to have one PC talk to another PC?  Can you provide some code or a UML model /confused

Comment: @Nascent_Notes my program runs by itself, I just added an option for it to get arguments from the url with code I showed. The python script just grabs the arguments to run from mywebsite.com/file.php for example arguments can be -timeout 50 and it will be used in the program. I just want a string inside my program to be what I specfiy remotely like the file.php script where I put the arguments and the program grabs it, What a better way to do that? The issue that it works but it seems Anti Virus detects it as some kind of a behavior and asks to allow or to deny.

Comment: @Nascent_Notes 1.Python 
`arguments = urllib.urlopen("http://website.com.info/file.php")

command = location + "\file.exe " + arguments.read()`
2. file.php has for example `-timeout 50 -logtofile no`
3. Python 
`subprocess.Popen(command),shell=True)`

and I can go to my website to file.php and change -timeout 60 -logtofile yes
and the python script will use other arguments

Comment: @Nascent_Notes I believe what I would to do is API?

Comment: Well API is not a verb/action, it's an application programming interace and it's more of a noun, so you wouldn't "API" so much as gain access or develop an API (not trying to be a jerk, but I want to make sure you understand what an API is).  Windows is warning you because you are opening subprocess.Popen to run commands.  Furthermore, invoking Popen() with shell=true is a security issue.  My guess is you aren't getting much response from the community because your problem wreaks of blackhat.  However, if this is truly a personal goal then you might want to download a file using ftp or wget...

Comment: once you got the file, just parse the file in whatever flavor you want and extract the values you want to pass as arguments.